# Compiz Desktop Effects

Tags: windows-xp, compiz

I have Windows XP, I want to have Compiz Desktop Effects. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to disappoint, but I'm fairly certain Compiz effects are linux only.

So the long and short of it: switch to linux if you want the compiz effects badly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Compiz is definitely X only. The best existing way to run X applications on MS Windows is Cygwin, but this won't solve your problem as the applications running "within" Cygwin won't affect the MS windows without Cygwin. So no, you cannot have the real Compiz.

If you are after a specific functionality, there may already be a Windows application which does what you need. For example, I missed the Compiz plugin Grid a lot until I found GridMove for Windows, which accomplishes the same task (albeit in a different way). So it may be worth to hunt around for such a thing, if it exists.

If you are just after some eye candy, upgrade your Windows. Aero looks much better. Besides, there are lots of other good reasons to get Windows 7, such as better security, improved usability, and better support for current hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awesome website that lists alernatives:
http://alternativeto.net/software/compiz/

From Alternative.to:

- Sysinternals Desktops (* my 60KB no-frills choice)
- Dexpot
- VirtualWin
- Switcher
- WindowsPager

Sadly, none of these support the much in the line of fancy 3D Effects you get with Compiz; The multi-desk functionality is pretty decent however.